# Python Selenium - Clicking pages without next button

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

[image]I would like to get info from multiple pages by clicking through them. The problem is there is not next button and even though the page link contains a number for counting through , as you can see in the image below.

Can anyone help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=2
While True:
    try:
        #some wait
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary spacebutton' and .='{}']".format(str(i+1))).click()
        i++
    except:
        break
```

Just loop through the a tags and click them based on their text.